# Mysql timestamp default value

Tags: mysql, database

Am really new to Mysql. Is it possible to do something like the following in some way? Mysql throws a syntax error as expected but is there something that I should change that would make it work?

```
CREATE TABLE tracksession(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             user_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
             leave_mode ENUM('loggedout', 'timedout') DEFAULT NULL,
             login TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
             logout TIMESTAMP DEFAULT ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE),
             PRIMARY KEY(ID));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope you cannot do this

```
DEFAULT ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE),
```

[explanation from the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-type-defaults.html) :

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

Must be a constant not a function ...